# How can I avoid the empty space of a bloc not displayed?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have to display or hide two outputpanels according to the selected radiobutton as you can see in the following code :

```
<p:outputLabel style="width:20%" value="Time unit"></p:outputLabel>
<p:selectOneRadio style="width:34%;margin-left:20%" id="choix" value="#{graphe.choix_aff}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Month" itemValue="mois" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Day" itemValue="jour" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hour" itemValue="heure" />
    <p:ajax update="panel1,panel2"  listener="#{graphe.handleChange}" />
</p:selectOneRadio>  

<p:outputPanel id="panel1">
    <p:calendar style="width:600px" rendered="#{graphe.display_cal()}" id="popup1" value="#{graphe.date1}">
    </p:calendar>
</p:outputPanel>  

<p:outputPanel id="panel2">
    <p:calendar style="width:600px" id="t" value="#{graphe.date3}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH" rendered="#{graphe.display_h()}">
    </p:calendar>
</p:outputPanel>
```

If I choose the option 'Hour', the calendar (panel2) will be shown after some empty lines (those of the panel1).

How can I solve this problem ?
Thank you.

Comment: The panel with unrendered calendar should result in a zero-height `div` being rendered, so it should be invisible. Why is it not zero-height? Maybe you have a CSS style that sets its height? You should inspect where those empty lines come from exactly with browser's developer tools.